# Help on theta region of polar double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I have a question about setting up the bounds on the theta integral of a polar double integral.

When you have a circle such as $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$, the equation of the circle can be shown to be $2\cos(\theta)$. So $r$ will go from $0$ to $2\cos(\theta)$. Fair enough.

But the theta. I have watched one excellent online video (Prof. Leonard) who has the theta range of this integral as $0$ to $\pi$. On the other hand, the Stewart Calculus book has this same problem with a limit of $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.

I know these may give the same answers, but which is the correct set up?

Thanks so much (and, yes, I've reviewed the other questions on the forum before posting this).

Comment: The range $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ seems more natural to me, since the circle is in the right half of the plane (where $x>0$).

Comment: The circle $r=2\cos\theta$ passes through the origin, so surely the cartesian equation for the circle is $$(x-1)^2+y^2=1.$$ IOW the radius of that circle is $1$ rather than $\sqrt2$ as your equation suggests.

Comment: Anyway, for all $\theta$ we have $\cos(\theta+\pi)=-\cos(\theta)$, Therefore $\theta$ and $\theta+\pi$ yield the exact same point. I think it follows that you can use any interval of length $\pi$ and get this circle. I agree with Nick in that the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ is a lot more natural.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I corrected that mistake, and the r is now 1.

Answer (score 1):

As it pointed in  Jyrki Lahtonen's comment if we consider $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$, then polar coordinates gives $0 \leqslant r \leqslant 2 \cos \theta$.
So we have region for $\theta$ from inequality $$0 \leqslant  \cos \theta$$
If initially we choose $ \theta \in (-\pi,  \pi]$, then we obtain solution $ \theta \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2},  \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.

Comment: @zhkuch, can you explain that a bit more. Maybe step by step, as I didn't follow your argument. And, as the first commenter noted, why is x>0 significant? I ask as I try to distill a general rule that will allow me to figure out similar, if different, problems.

Comment: @user27847. We have $x = r \cos \theta$, so, $x \geqslant 0$ is exactly that condition which gives $0 \leqslant \cos \theta$, because $r \geqslant 0$. Same for conclusion in my answer: we have $0 \leqslant 2\cos \theta$, which leaves $0 \leqslant \cos \theta$. Feel free to ask more if/when need it.

Comment: That makes sense. So to generalize. For any circle in x>0, will the range always be -pi/2 to pi/2. Similarly, for a circle where r = asin(theta), will the region always be 0 to pi?

Comment: Not for any where $x \geqslant 0$. We should take in account all conditions. For example $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=1$ gives $\theta \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, because here we have also $y \geqslant 0$, which adds $\sin \theta \geqslant 0$.

Comment: thanks for your insights. And sorry to be thick about this! So, tell me if this is the right way to approach the theta boundary question. Take a circle with radius 1, centered at (1,0), like in my original problem. Here, x>=0 at all times, but y is both positive and negative. So the real limit is x>= 0, which means a range from -pi/2 to pi/2 as this is where cosine is positive. In your example of a circle centered at (1,1), both sin and cos are always positive, and this occurs only in 0 to pi/2. more....

Comment: And if the circle were centered at (-1,1) (e.g., all in the 2nd quadrant), we'd have y >=0 (ergo sin >=0), but x<=0 (ergo cosine <=0), so we'd need a region where both of these are fulfilled. This occurs at pi/2 to pi. Similarly, if the circle were at (-1,-1), we'd need sin and cos <=0. This occurs from pi to 3pi/2. And centered at (1,-1), we'd need cos>=0 and sin<=0, which occurs from 3pi/2 to 2pi. Does this seem like a generalizable approach?

Comment: Your views are in right direction, only, if I correctly understand your intentions, as you want to have general scheme to work with angle in polar coordinates, you need to obtain outcome from formal inequalities individually in each separate case. Maybe some circle is in some $[\theta, \theta+ \alpha]$ ray, as for example is for $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=\frac{1}{4}$. Let me also advice in such case use "extended" polar coordinates $x-1=r\cos \theta, y-1=r \sin \theta$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the time you have given to this. Very grateful.